# SettingWithCopyWarning creating a new column. Several options excuted but same result obtained

Tags: python-2.7, warnings

I'm retrieving a SettingWithCopyWarning when I'm trying to create a new column that is a copy from another one, just changing date format.

What I'm executing is:

```
df2['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.fecha)
df2['fechanorm'] = df2['fecha'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

being fecha a field containing a date in one format and being fechanorm a new field in which I want to store the same date with other format.

After reading other available post I have tried other option for the second senteces but all of them with the same warning:

```
df2.loc[:,'fechanorm'] = df2.loc[:,'fecha'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df2['fechanorm'] = df2.loc[:,'fecha'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

How can I remove this warning?